# Parsing Variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I run this script I get NullReferenceException. When I call the script the Awake function call and works and returns the 3 variables with values stored in them, then when the WindowFunction function is called the variables empty again. I've tested the code and that's what I've found and unity is obeying the call order so it cannot be that either.

```
private Rect windowRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;
private int BSpace;
string[][] MeetRequests;

string[,] SortedStudentArray;
string[][] StudentArray;
string[][] userArray;
public int ItemSpacing = 10;
public int ItemWidth = 80;
public int ItemHeight = 30;

//when this script is first called
void Start()
{
    //Fetches all user Data
    string[][] userArray = GetComponent<Userdata>().CallDetail();

    string[][] StudentArray = GetComponent<Userdata>().UserSorting(userArray);

    //Calls the SortStudentArray method
    string[,] SortedStudentArray = SortStudentList();
}


public void OnGUI()
{
    //create a window
    GUI.Window(0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Meeting Request Viewer");
}
public void WindowFunction(int windowID)
{
            //Creates a box with a scrolling bar to taverse the y axis
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(Screen.width / 6, Screen.height / 6, 350, 250), scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 300, 30 * SortedStudentArray.Length));

    for (int studentRow = 0; studentRow < SortedStudentArray.Length; studentRow++)
    {
        int NextItem = (ItemSpacing + ItemHeight) * studentRow;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(ItemSpacing, NextItem, ItemWidth, ItemHeight), SortedStudentArray[studentRow, 6]);
    }


    GUI.EndScrollView();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've read the post before but I believe that my problem is to do with the parsing of variable as opposed to anything else

Comment: In that case you should reduce your code to a [mcve] there's way too much "noise" here

Comment: That should be better

Comment: So, your `Start` method creates a bunch of local variables that are then discarded - I don't see you assigning to the member variables anywhere

Comment: How do I go about assigning them then?

Comment: @Oscar don't specify a type in front of the variable name in your Start() method.

Comment: You've moved your arrays. See how it should look in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543835/9481503)

Comment: Had to close this. Inside the start function, remove `string[][]` from `userArray` and `StudentArray` then `string[,]` from `SortedStudentArray`. If you don't you are declaring the variables again instead of initializing the global ones.